# array is not going to next position via for looop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here is my code:

ArrayFunHouseTwo

```
public class ArrayFunHouseTwo
{
//goingUp() will return true if all numbers
//in numArray are in increasing order
//[1,2,6,9,23] returns true
//[9, 11, 13, 8]  returns false
public static boolean goingUp(int[] numArray)
{
    int num = 0;
    int numMinus = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x < numArray.length; x++){
        System.out.println(x);
        num = numArray[x];
        numMinus = numArray[x-1];

        if(num > numMinus){
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;           
}
```

and the associated runner class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab14b
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    int[] one = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int[] two = {1,2,3,9,11,20,30};
    //add more test cases
    //int[] three = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,-2};
    //int[] four = {3,6,9,12,15,18,21,23,19,17,15,13,11,10,9,6,3,2,1,0};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one));
    System.out.println("is going Up ?  " + ArrayFunHouseTwo.goingUp(one));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(two));
    System.out.println("is going Up ?  " + ArrayFunHouseTwo.goingUp(two));
    //add more test cases
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(three));
    //System.out.println("is going Up ?  " + ArrayFunHouseTwo.goingUp(three));
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(four));
    //System.out.println("is going Up ?  " + ArrayFunHouseTwo.goingUp(four));
```

I'm wanting it to print out and thus, prove that it is reading though the whole array, but the only array it's reading through is the third one and it will print all the values at position x or the value of x, depending on how I code the `println()` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(num > numMinus){
    return true;
}
```

This means that as soon as you find a number greater than its previous number, it will terminate the loop. What you want to do at this point is something like this.

```
...
    if(num <= numMinus){
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

edit: fixed the condition to `<=` basically you check consecutive numbers and if the numbers are equal or decreasing, you set a flag to false (indeed at this point you can return false)

Comment: no, it's supposed to only return true if all the numbers in the array are increasing (or decreasing, but that's a different method) and false if decreasing for `.goingUp` or false if it does both (like array four)

Comment: So since my `.goingDown` method would be the opposite, I'd just need to adjust the appropriate values, right?

Comment: @tech_geek23 yup, just the condition - it would be `>=`. I would rewrite the two functions into one somehow, perhaps take the direction (up or down) as a parameter

Comment: that logically would make since, but this is how it was structured when I opened the file...

Comment: @tech_geek23 you can still have a 3rd function doing the actual checking and the two functions just act as wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a couple of problems.

Start your for loop with x=0. All arrays in Java start from 0 and run to array length-1, meaning your x < numArray.length is correct (think it through if you don't follow that).

System.out.println(x); will print out the value of x, which merely your counter.

System.out.println(numArray[x]); will print out the contents of your array at the x value (ie: starting at 0 through to the last at length-1)

numMinus = numArray[x-1]; is going to cause you problems as you cannot look at a -1 index. Instead compare the value at x with the value at x+1.
ie: (numArray[x] < numArray[x+1]) should return true
Because you are looking at numArray[x+1], alter the condition in you for loop to x < numArray.length-1, otherwise you will end up creating an error for looking past the end of the array.

Currently you are returning the result of the very first comparison as the return breaks your loop, I'm pretty sure you want the result only after checking all values, at least until you either get a false or run out of values.

Create a boolean value within this function and use it to keep track of whether each pair is true or not. If the value turns false, return it. Otherwise return the (it can only be true) value at the end of the function.

Dunno if I got all of the problems, but fix these and you will be well on the way.